# Removing substring from string variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash string variable:

```
switches="-r cc -c 1,2,3,4 -u"
```

where numbers 1,2,3,4 can be any integer, like:

-c 25,45,78,34.

Moreover, it can be with fewer numbers, like:

-c 1

-c 1,2

or

-c 1,2,3,4

It can't be like:
-c 1,2,3

So -c can have one, two, or four integers only.

I forgot to mention that that this pattern can appeares also at the beginning, or at the end of the string variable $switches too, like:

-r cc -u -c 1,2,3,4

-r cc -u -c 1,2,3

And one more thing: this pattern can be appeared in the $switches variable only once.

How can I remove the '-c 1,2,3,4 ' part of switches variable using just bash?
I tried with this:

```
switches=${switches/ -c /}
```

but get this:

-r cc1,2,3,4 -u

I expect this:

-r cc -u

Best, Pal

Comment: You are already doing it wrong in the first line. `switches` should be an array, not a regular variable: `switches=(-r cc -c 1,2,3,4 -u)`.

Comment: The switches array could have more then those three values: (-r cc), (-c 1,2,3,4), (-u). switches array can have maximum 17 string values.

Comment: The switches array could have more then those three values: (-r cc), (-c 1,2,3,4), (-u). switches array can have maximum 17 string values. (-r cc) is one value in the array, (-c 1,2,3,4) or (-c 1) or (-c 1,2) is another value, (-u) is another value, (-g) is another, and so on. In this case switches=(-r cc -c 1,2,3,4 -u) is not the proper way for creating the switches array, right?

Comment: Then it should be created like this: switches=('-r cc' '-c 1,2,3,4' '-u' '-g'). But then how can I remove a value of that array, because value '-c 1,2,3,4' cod vary like this: '-c 1' '-c 1,2' '-c 1,2,3,4' ?

Comment: OK, I can arrange so so in switches array every values goes in to right place, like this: switches=('-r cc' '-l l' '-c 1,2,3,4' '-g' '-e none' '-f 15' '-o 5' '-u' '-t 50' '-s 0' '-S 200' '-a 0' '-p 0' '-T' '-b white' '-F 10' '-i 1') so eg. '-t 50' could have always the index number of 8. So how can then remove such a value from the switches array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
shopt -s extglob                         # enables extended globbing
switches=${switches//-c *([^ ])}
```

- `*([^ ])`: matches any number of non-spaces

---

This will leave you with unnecessary spaces. More complicated solution:

```
switches=${switches//-c *([^ ])*( )}
switches=${switches/%*( )}
```

- `*([^ ])*( )`: matches any number of non-spaces and any number of spaces after
- `${switches/%*( )}`: if the last option is also `-c`, the code above wouldn't remove the spaces left by it. `/%*( )` removes any number of spaces from the end

Comment: This code did it:  `switches=${switches//-c *([^ ])*( )}`. Thank you very much!